# Websocket: what is the purpose text/binary frame indicator

Tags: websocket

I am implementing a WebSocket server in C and was wondering what's the purpose of the text/binary frame indicators (opcode 1 and 2). Why they are there? In the end in both cases the payload contains bits. And when there is a protocol using websocket or so then I know what expect in the data. Is it because when it's a text message I can be sure that payload only contains UTF-8 valid data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will start my answer by pointing out that WebSockets are often implemented with a Javascript client in mind (i.e., a browser).

When you're using C, the different opcode might be used in different ways, but when using Javascript, this difference controls the type of the data in the event ([`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) vs. [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)).

As you point out in the question, a string is always a valid UTF-8 stream of bytes, whereas a `blob` isn't.

This affects some data transport schemes (such as JSON parsing, which requires a UTF-8 valid stream).

Obviously, in C, this opcode could be used in different ways, but it would be better to use the opcode in the same manner as a potential javascript client.

*P.S.*

There are a number of Websocket C libraries and frameworks out there (I'm the author of [facil.io](http://facil.io)).

Unless this is a study project, I would consider using one of the established frameworks / libraries.